# Auto Fill a Windows Form using WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms

I am currently using a windows application in which there are many lengthy forms to be filled out. This is a commercial tool which I have bought so I don't have any access to the code. In order to save the pain of filling these huge forms I wanted to create a WPF application which does some calculations and auto fill the forms for me. So is there any way my WPF app can fill the form which is open in the other window?

Comment: Just so that you're aware, WPF has no bearing on the solution to the problem. WPF is only a way of dealing with your current application, it has no functionality to deal with windows outside of your own application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [Windows Automation API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd561932%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)